# how can the answer be the same even though the integral isn't?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-integral-formula

Is there a mistake in the following? I think there is because for $a>0$ $I(a)$ equals to the expression which includes $e^{-a}$ but for $b>0$ it is still $e^{-b}$ even though in the integral there is $e^{-ib \xi}$. So the answer is same even though the integral being evaluated isn't.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that with $I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ia\xi}}{\xi^2-2\xi+2}\,d\xi$, then $\overline{I(a)}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ia\xi}}{\xi^2-2\xi+2}\,d\xi$, which for $a<0$ can be expressed as

$$\overline{I(a)}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i|a|\xi}}{\xi^2-2\xi+2}\,d\xi\tag1$$

The right-hand side of $(1)$ can be evaluated using contour integration by closing the contour in the upper-half plane.  The result for $a<0$ is

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i|a|\xi}}{\xi^2-2\xi+2}\,d\xi&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{i|a|\xi}}{\xi^2-2\xi+2}, \xi=z_2=1+i\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \frac{e^{-|a|}(\cos(|a|)+i\sin(|a|))}{2i}\\\\
&=\pi e^{-|a|} (\cos(|a|)+i\sin(|a|))\\\\
&=\pi e^{-|a|} (\cos(a)+i\sin(a))\\\\
\end{align}$$

whence exploiting the fact that the sine function is odd, we find that

$$I(a)=\pi e^{-|a|}(\cos(a)+i\sin(a))$$

as was to be shown.

---

Alternatively, for $a<0$, we close the contour in the lower-half plane and find

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ia\xi}}{\xi^2-2\xi+2}\,d\xi&=-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{ia\xi}}{\xi^2-2\xi+2}, \xi=z_2=1-i\right)\\\\
&=-2\pi i \frac{e^{a}(\cos(a)+i\sin(a))}{-2i}\\\\
&=\pi e^a (\cos(a)+i\sin(a))\\\\
&=\pi e^{-|a|} (\cos(a)+i\sin(a))\\\\
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: why did you start the evaluation with $ -2pi i $ rather than $2pi i $

Comment: When closing the contour in the lower-half plane, the contour is traversed clockwise instead of counter clockwise.

Comment: oh yes thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.